# Specifying Disk Drive to Write Files?

Tags: linux, tar

After `tar.gz`'ing a 25 GB folder, I copied the file from my local machine to a remote server via scp.

Once the file was transferred, I failed to extract the tar.gz due to:

```
$ tar -zxvf dump.tar.gz
myFolder/
myFolder/myFile1        

tar: myFolder/myFile: Wrote only 9728 of 10240 bytes

myFolder/myFile2
tar: myFolder/myFile2: Cannot write: No space left on device
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Then, I ran `df -h` to see that the disk is "100%" full:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_00-lv_root
                       16G   15G   28M 100% /
tmpfs                 7.9G  136K  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M  131M  329M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_00-lv_opt
                      7.3G  152M  6.8G   3% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_u01
                      148G  6.4G  134G   5% /u01
```

Can I specify `scp` to write to the `dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_u01` disk drive since it has enough space? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about `scp` but the problem of writing to a full device appeared with `tar`.

I understand the question that you want to copy the file(s) to the filesystem on the `dev/mapper/vg_01-lv_u01` volume. For this you must use the mount point `/u01` as the destination.

### scp

```
scp dump.tar.gz user@machine:/u01/any/existing/path
```

This way you specify the destination path in the mount point of the volume you want to use.

### tar

`tar` allows you to specify the destination directory for extraction too.

```
tar -zxvf dump.tar.gz -C /u01/any/existing/path
```

### combination

If you use the `tar` file just for the transport you can use a more direct way to pipe it directly through `ssh`:

```
tar -cf - /source/directory | ssh user@machine "tar -xf - -C /u01/any/existing/path"
```

If you use compression with `ssh`, the compression with `tar` will not probably be needed. Anyway you can enable the compression anytime by putting the `z` option of `tar` back.

Comment: Thanks. Since I already have the tar.gz transferred, could I just `mv` it to `/u01/...`?

Comment: @Kevin: You are welcome. Yes, of course, you can move the file to the other filesystem. If you do not need to keep the archive, you can directly extract and remove it: `tar -zxvf dump.tar.gz -C /u01/any/existing/path && rm dump.tar.gz` **Edit:** I have changed the commands here so that `rm` is executed only after successful extraction of the archive.